# Enum to Class in C#

Tags: c#, class, properties, enums

I have one Enum like this:

```
public enum CommonMessage : ushort
{
    val =1,
    val2 = 2,
    val3 = 3
 }
```

I have to send this data to other application. Communication is happening between my application and other through comport(serialCommunication).

I'm getting back to data to my application also .

I want  convert this Enum to class. Please tell me how Can I do this.
what should be the data type of the variables.

Comment: Are you sure that is really what you want to do? enums and classes are used for completely different purposes

Comment: Not sure what the issue you're having might be. An enum is a primitive type, it can be easily serialised and deserialised. Why do you need it to be a class?

Comment: What do you mean by *I want convert this Enum to class*? If you want to send to another application just send the integer representation of the enum value and call `Enum.ToObject` in another application.

Comment: Yeah I know that enums and Classes are used for different purpose but in my requirement I have to packetised  in form of class because I have to send this data to other application every 5 secs. I think Class would be best option because value will change after receiving data from other application.

Comment: @Charlie check language which you are using

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An enum is basically a set of named constants that represent numbers. So you can just convert the type to it's numeric equivalent and then convert whatever is returned back accordingly. So if you wanted to pass the value to an application, you could convert the enum to it's numeric type:

```
var myEnumNumericValue = (ushort)CommonMessage.val; //would represent "CommonMessage.val"
```

When your application sends back a value it would be a number, and you can convert it back accordingly:

```
var enumValue = (CommonMessage)returnValue; //where return value is an ushort
```

Answer (score 0):

If you MUST send class, send an Int32 - it is the smallest form of an enum value.

Your connected client can parse that locally allowing for different technologies, i.e a JavaScript client could implement a matching enum or you could use a reference to the same enum in a .Net client. Either way, it should still be an int and easy to transfer.

Hope that helps.